# How should I mount a downtube shifter clamp that lacks a locating hole?

Tags: shifter

Usually, the band on downtube shifters has a hole that fits over a dimple on the tube, like this:

[image: downtube shifters mounting band with hole]

The band on this pair of downtube shifters lacks this hole:

[image: downtube shifters mounting band without hole]

I can't put them over the dimple; it would damage the band. Would you mount them above, or below it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above, so that the tension on the cables can't pull the clamp down.

Comment: OP might be prepared to grind the dimple off and then touch up the paint,  or put a matching locating hole in the band.  But your suggestion is what I'd try.